# C++ STL vector init

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I am just wondering how I could solve this problem.

I have a

```
vector<char> vstr;
```

definition in the class Program.

Then in the class constructor I want to init this vector with an array:

```
char arrayOfChars[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

this.vstr = new vector<string>(arrayOfChars, arrayOfChars + sizeof(arrayOfChars)/sizeof(arrayOfChar[0]));
```

The build gives me a bug:

> error: request for member 'vstr' int 'this', which is of non-class type 'Program *const' .

Could you give me a simple solution for this error?

Comment: Aside: you would probably be best served by reading up on how to write C++ code, rather than looking for a quick fix for writing java-like code.

Comment: `this` is a pointer in C++, so must be dereferenced.   Within non-static member functions, `this` is usually implied (no need to type it).   But if you do need it, either use `this->vstr` or the equivalent `(*this).vstr`.   Like Hurkl said, don't try to write Java-like code in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in C++ but I see at least two problems:

1. You are trying to initialise an object with a pointer. Don't use `new` key word.
2. What is more this pointer points to vector of strings not chars, so replace `vector<string>` with `vector<char>`.
3. As `melak47` says in his comment `this.vstr` is also incorrect because this is a pointer and therefore should be replaced with `this->vstr` or simply `vstr`

Once you make all the three corrections it should compile

Comment: btw, I would like the down voter to explain the reason for the down vote

Comment: Just to mention, I got this vector<type> constructor, with the new keyword from the http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/ site.

Answer (score 1):

I think that piece of code is  what you want.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Program {
    vector<char> vstr;
public:
    Program(const char* data)
    {
        string s(data);
        std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(vstr));
    }
    void PrintData()
    {
        for (auto it = vstr.begin(); it != vstr.end(); it++)
        {
            std::cout << (*it);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Program p("simple data");
    p.PrintData();
}
```

Comment: You don't need a temporary string, you can do `vstr.assign(data, data + strlen(data));`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The iterator used in the cycle helps me a lot, and the mention of not using new keyword also! God bless you!